# List only files of a particular extension with the DIR command

Tags: windows-7, command-line, dir

On Windows, we can see directory content using the `DIR` command.

I want to know, how can one see the list of only those files which have particular extension, e.g I want to see list of all `.txt` files, what command I should run?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Dir supports wildcards, so:

```
dir *.txt
```

Comment: It does quite a bit more also, try...Dir /?

Comment: i tried but it did not show me * option, rest i know.

Comment: This doesn't quite what the OP wants, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423935

Answer (score 8):

You can list only the filenames without the extra information added with the command
 `dir /b *.[extension]`.

A more comprehensive list can be found [here](https://www.windows-commandline.com/dir-command-line-options/) .

Answer (score 7):

```
dir /S *.txt
```

will show files with ".txt" suffix in specified directory and all sub-directories.